# How to filter data on a monthly basis and form the appropriate arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have collections that come from the server after a client request (date range).

For example, incoming data, after which I form the length of the array:

- 2018/04/12 and 2018/10/12 => array.length = 7 (months)
- 2018/05/12 and 2018/10/12 => array.length = 6 (months)
- 2018/09/12 and 2018/10/12 => array.length = 2 (months)

A response comes from the server in the form of collections that correspond to the requested date range by the **date_call** parameter

For example:

Requested data: **2018/10/01** and **2018/10/12**

if the document on the **date_call** parameter corresponds to the requested range (**for example, date_call = 2018/10 /01..12**) - send the response in the following form

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb299f06229dddbaab553b"),
    "phone" : "+38 (031) 231-23-21",
    "date_call" : "2018-10-08",
    "adress_delivery" : "1",
    "quantity_concrete" : "1",
    "state" : "200",
    "comments" : "1",
    "is_order" : "n",
    "date_delivery" : "",
    "quantity_orders" : "",
    "summ_order" : "",
    "profit" : "",
    "id" : "0"
}
```

### There may be many such collections.

---

In data.labels, I have an array with the names of the months that was requested (which I formed in array - Months).

In datasets.data there will be 3 arrays - **DataCalls**, **DataOrders**, **DataProfit**

1. In **DataCalls**, the amount of call documents (date_call) monthly
2. In **DataOrders** - the amount of the number of orders (is_order)
   monthly
3. In **DataProfit** - the amount of profit (profit) monthly

QUESTION(s):

- What is the best way to create arrays of Data Calls, Data Orders,
  Data Profit?
- Or is it perhaps better to form approximately such an
  object in JSON right away?

```
    {
        "Month": "April",
        "Calls": 75,
        "Orders": "20",
        "Profit": "1500"
    }
```

Here is screenshot desirable result with right data

[image]

Comment: I don't ask me to write ready-made code, I just need a side view of the problem and a hint in the best solution.
I have already formed an array of labels (of the month), but it seems to me that this is not an entirely correct approach.
Perhaps it is better to form JSON and extract the necessary arrays?  That is what I do not quite understand how best to do ..

Answer (score 0):

JSON is definitely the way to go here, but I'd advise adding the "year" property to your JSON object as well so that you can then execute date calculations if needed on the front end. You could go even deeper and send the actual transactions and do the calculation on the front end.